# How to calculate recurring/repeating monthly events (e.g. first Friday)?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to calculate dates for things like 1st Friday or 3rd Saturday?

Answer (score 0):

I took [Dave Peterson's answer from 2005(!)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.misc/a1hrSd9ALi8) and adapted it a bit so you can drag down in google sheets.

Example for 3rd saturdays:
In A1, put `"DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1+7*3)
    -WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),8-7))"`

In A2, put `"DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1+7*3)
    -WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,8-7))"`

[image]

That will calculate the year based off your current date. The part that is controlling the week number (ie 3rd or 1st) is that `7*3`(3rd week) part. That part that is controlling the day of the week is the `8-7` part. Still trying to grok that. The +1 is adding a month, thus allowing you to do a fill down.

Test this against google calendar to get it right. Hope this can help someone stuck!

Make a copy of it if you'dlike: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lOroSjy9EXLoiu-kDE3w1EMWw42HMIG7YJ3iGNhpl34/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

For the first five mondays from March 2018,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2018,3,),ROW(A1:A5),"0111111"))
```

Uses string method of WORKDAY.INTL to declare specific weekday as the only working day.

For third Saturday of each month from March 2018,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2018,ROW(A3:A12),),3,"1111101"))
```

Comment: Any chance you could explain how this works a bit more? Which part is Saturday vs. Monday? How does one customize it more?

Comment: 0111111! got it